# how to overwrite camera style in react-native-camera-kit?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I use this component for scan qr , but its height width are not change,
its style are not working , how can i define its width and height specific like 50,50

```
<CameraKitCameraScreen
        style={{
            width:'100%',height:'100%',
            backgroundColor: 'white'
          }}
          cameraOptions={{
            flashMode: 'auto',                
            focusMode: 'on',                 
            zoomMode: 'on',                   
            ratioOverlay:'1:1',               
            ratioOverlayColor: '#00000077'    
          }}
          showFrame={true}
          //Show/hide scan frame
          scanBarcode={true}
          offsetForScannerFrame = {50}
          heightForScannerFrame = {50}
          hideControls={true} 
          //Can restrict for the QR Code only
          laserColor={'blue'}
          //Color can be of your choice
          frameColor={'yellow'}
          //If frame is visible then frame color
          colorForScannerFrame={'green'}
          //Scanner Frame color
          onReadCode={event =>
            this.onBarcodeScan(event.nativeEvent.codeStringValue)
          }
        />
```

Answer (score 2):

you're taking `CameraKitCameraScreen`, instead take `Camera` from that library like this,

`import {  CameraType, Camera } from 'react-native-camera-kit'`

```
        <Camera
            style={{ width:Dimensions.get('window').width, height:Dimensions.get('window').width, justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center'}}
            cameraType={CameraType.Back}
            scanBarcode={true}
            onReadCode={(event: any) => Alert.alert('QR code found', event.nativeEvent.codeStringValue)} // optional
            showFrame={false} // (default false) optional, show frame with transparent layer (qr code or barcode will be read on this area ONLY), start animation for scanner,that stoped when find any code. Frame always at center of the screen
            laserColor={Colors.primary} // (default red) optional, color of laser in scanner frame
            frameColor={Colors.primary} // (default white) optional, color of border of scanner frame
            focusMode={'false'}
            ratioOverlay={'1:1'} cameraRatioOverlay={undefined} 
            captureButtonImage={undefined} 
            captureButtonImageStyle={{}} 
            cameraFlipImage={undefined} 
            cameraFlipImageStyle={{}} 
            hideControls={undefined} 
            torchOnImage={undefined} 
            torchOffImage={undefined} 
            torchImageStyle={{}} 
            onBottomButtonPressed={function (event: any): void {
                throw new Error('Function not implemented.')
            } }        />
```

[image]